# I can't find a way to get data from gremlin-server, using node/express - promise {<pending>} forever

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, gremlin

Before you read on too far, this question might be about Node/Express or it might be about Gremlin - I can't work out which is the cause?

On my Linux box as SU, I've started Janusgraph:
`docker run --name janusgraph-default --volume /home/greg/Downloads/gremlin:/dataImports janusgraph/janusgraph:latest` (I mount a local folder, to pick up the `air-routes.graphml` file)

On the same box, in a new terminal I start gremlin-server: `docker run --rm --link janusgraph-default:janusgraph -e GREMLIN_REMOTE_HOSTS=janusgraph -it janusgraph/janusgraph:latest ./bin/gremlin.sh` (which gives me a gremlin console)

From the gremlin console, I can run `:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml`

Then `:> graph.io(graphml()).readGraph("/dataImports/air-routes.graphml")`

Finally: `:> g.V().has('airport','code','DFW').values()`, which returns the details for Dallas Fort Worth, as expected.

Having demonstrated that I've loaded the data successfully and can query it from the console, I want to create a Node/Express program that will ultimately run some generally static queries to build a series of dashboard pages.

I have cobbled together my first Express app:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

const gremlin = require('gremlin');
const traversal = gremlin.process.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;
const __ = gremlin.process.statics;
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;
const column = gremlin.process.column;
const direction = gremlin.process.direction;
const p = gremlin.process.P;
const textp = gremlin.process.TextP;
const pick = gremlin.process.pick;
const pop = gremlin.process.pop;
const order = gremlin.process.order;
const scope = gremlin.process.scope;
const t = gremlin.process.t;
// const tq = traversal().withRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin'));
const tq = traversal().withRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182'));
const g = tq;

router.get('/home', (req,res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Hello World,</h1><p>This is home router</p>');
});

// my first pass
// router.get('/query', async (req,res) => {
//     const response = await gremlinQuery();
//     //const response = gremlinQuery();
//     const resp = res.send(response);
// });

//my second pass
router.get('/query', (req,res) => {
  const response = gremlinQuery();
  console.log(response);
  const resp = res.send(response);
});

//<snipped out other router.gets>

app.use('/', router);

app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);

console.log('Web Server is listening at port '+ (process.env.port || 3000));

async function gremlinQuery() {
  let results;
//function gremlinQuery() {
    try{
        const results = await g.V().has('airport', 'code', 'LHR').values().toList();
        console.log(results);
        //JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<results>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results2));
        var arr = JSON.parse(results);
        console.log('output: ' + arr);
        return('output: ' + arr);
    } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
    }
}
```

The query in the code returns the expected result in gremlin-console but in this code (which I run in debug mode in VSCode) it launches the expected webpage on `localhost:3000` but without the expected JSON response data and on the debug terminal it stops at `Promise {<pending>}` and I can't work out whether I'm
a) not connecting to the gremlin-server?
b) have made a mess of my async/await (is it OK that it's on the function called by the router function?)
c) Something else

(got to say the 'net isn't awash with Node/Express/Gremlin/Janusgraph examples to draw on.)

---

Docker version 19.03.11, build 42e35e61f352

Linux xxxxxxxx 5.3.18-lp152.60-default #1 SMP Tue Jan 12 23:10:31 UTC 2021 (9898712) x86_64
x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gremlin>  Gremlin.version() ==>3.4.6

node --version v14.15.4

express ??

Answer (score 0):

`gremlinQuery` is a async function, then you have wait until the function `resolve` a result.

And `gremlinQuery` look like an unused function (???)

How about

```
async function gremlinQuery() {
  const results = await g.V().has('airport', 'code', 'LHR').values().toList();
  // return JSON.parse(results); // results is a string???
  return results;
}
```

express router

```
router.get('/query', async (req, res) => { // async handle
  try {
    const response = await gremlinQuery(); // wait until the query response
    // res.send(response);
    res.json(response); // send it to client as a json object
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error); // Notice to client - Some thing went wrong
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @hoandgdv. That helped, insofar as I've now isolated the problem (I think) to `const results = await g.V().has('airport', 'code', 'LHR').values().toList();`  Using VSCode's debugger, I could step through to that line at which point it stopped responding  - presumably 'awaiting' a response, which seemed to never arrive. I wonder if the gremlin websocket connection isn't connected as I'd presumed or perhaps if my traversal query is malformed. How can I work out which (or other problem)?

Comment: I Just tried again, stepping into the different parts of the traversal query line but all the way through and to the end, the variable `results` remained 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but there is a name is effect to create client variable because of the same problem m facing but when using the same constant name as per the document then it's work

**Doc variable sample**

```
const authenticator = new Gremlin.driver.auth.PlainTextSaslAuthenticator(
  `/dbs/${GREMLIN_DATABASE}/colls/${GREMLIN_GRAPH}`,
  GREMLIN_PRIMARY_KEY
);

const client = new Gremlin.driver.Client(GREMLIN_ENDPOINT, {
  authenticator,
  traversalsource: "g",
  rejectUnauthorized: true,
  mimeType: "application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json",
});
```